# Connect 4 regardless of which cells is clicked on a grid find the bottom cell and change its image

Tags: c#, xamarin

All grid cells are white images which  are initially set to 0 and when clicked are either set to 1 or 2 depending on the color.

I cant figure out how to make it so regardless of which white image the user clicks it will go to the bottom of that column, find the last cell with the value of 0 and fill that cell with the colored tile.

```
string[] imagePaths = { "empty.png", "Yellow.png", "Red.png" };
    const int NumberOfCells = 36;
    const int WidthOfBoard = 6;

    //defualt player
    string playersTurn = "Red";

    int[] boardValues = new int[NumberOfCells];
    ImageButton[] buttons = new ImageButton[NumberOfCells];

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCells; i++)
        {
            buttons[i] = (ImageButton)board.FindByName("cell" + i);
        }

        ResetGame();
        Rules();
    }

    //put image of blue or red tile on grid and update turn
    private async void Cell_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;

        int y = (int)button.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
        int x = (int)button.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);

        int index = (y * WidthOfBoard) + x;


        if (boardValues[index] == 0)
        {
           
            {
                button.TranslationY = -400;
                buttons[index].Source = playersTurn + ".png";

                if (playersTurn == "Yellow")
                {
                    boardValues[index] = 1;
                    CheckForWinner();
                    playersTurn = "Red";
                }
                else
                {
                    boardValues[index] = 2;
                    CheckForWinner();
                    playersTurn = "Yellow";
                }

                turnLabel.Text = playersTurn + "'s Turn";
                await button.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250);
            }
        }

    }
```

[How the board looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOhv1.png)

Comment: Draw a picture of your grid, and number each cell with it's index in the array - the upper right cell will be 0, and the lower left will be 35.  Then you can easily see what the index value you need to check for each column.  For example, the 2nd column  (index 1) will be (from top down) 1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31.  So the last row in any column will be that column's index +30, and each row above will be -6

Comment: Or, create an enum (Empty, Red, Yellow). Create a 2D array of those representing the grid. Create a function that translates from a point on the screen to a 2D index into that array. Make your `Paint` handler work with that array (so that the array is your one _source of truth_). When you get a click, translate it to a cell using that function. Check if it's Empty. If it is, walk down that column in the array till you get a non-empty cell